# UWP : open a ProgressRing when a page is loaded

Tags: uwp, progress-bar

On the first page of my UWP app, I have an "add" button in a CommandBar that opens a second page.

At the opening of this second page, I load a list from a SQLite table and I filter this list. It is a process that is relatively long because there is a lot of data.

When I click the Add button on the first page, it remains highlighted throughout the process of loading the list, and the second page only opens when the list is loaded in memory.

I would like the second page to open as soon as the user clicks the Add button, and display a ProgressRing instead of the ListView, the time to run the data loading.

I tried to put a ProgressRing on the first page:

```
private void AddFavori_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyProgressRing.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    Frame.Navigate(typeof(ChoixFavoris), currentListeAchat);
}
```

However, nothing is displayed. It's the same thing on the second page:

```
public ChoixFavoris()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    MyProgressRing.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    currentListeAchat = e.Parameter as ListeAchats;
    textBlock.Text = currentListeAchat.NomListe;
    majtableArticles();
    //
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    // Register for hardware and software back request from the system
    SystemNavigationManager systemNavigationManager = SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView();
    systemNavigationManager.BackRequested += OnBackRequested;
    MyProgressRing.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

How to do it? Thank you to anyone who can help me.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like the second page to open as soon as the user clicks the Add button, and display a ProgressRing instead of the ListView, the time to run the data loading. I tried to put a ProgressRing on the first page:

You'd better make the `majtableArticles()` method as an asynchronous method. And putting the ProgressRing control on the second page would be better.

If you don't know how to make an asynchronous method, please see [Asynchronous programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/threading-async/asynchronous-programming-universal-windows-platform-apps).

I've made a simple code sample for your reference. I just used `await Task.Delay(10000)` to simulate your time-consuming loading data operation.

```cs
//MainPage.xaml.cs
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Frame.Navigate(typeof(BlankPage1));
}
```

```xml
<!--BalnkPage1.xaml-->
<Grid>
    <ProgressRing x:Name="progressring" Height="100" Width="100" Visibility="Collapsed" IsActive="False"></ProgressRing>
</Grid>
```

```cs
protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    progressring.IsActive = true;
    progressring.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    await Task.Delay(10000);
    progressring.IsActive = false;
    progressring.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

***[Updated on 2018/8/1]***

@Marcel Delhaye This just a simple sample about how to convert a synchronization method to asynchronous method.

```cs
private void Test()
{
    while (true)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
    }
}
```

```cs
private async Task TestAsync()
{
    await Task.Run(() => {
        while (true)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
        }
    });
}
```

```cs
//on BalnkPage1.xaml.cs
protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    progressring.IsActive = true;
    progressring.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    await TestAsync(); 
    progressring.IsActive = false;
    progressring.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.
The problem is that data loading (MajtableArticles () method) contains no APIs that I can call with await. So I don't see how I could make this method asynchronous.
I bypassed the problem by adding on the first page the code I found on the page:
Https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29381626/progressring-is-not-showing-while-the-app-runs
This is not so good, but the user does not feel that the program is crashed.
Thanks anyway.

Comment: @MarcelDelhaye Why did you think rhat you cannot make an asynchronous method? Just because you do not have an awaitable method in it? That's incorrect. Please see my updated reply. I made a sample to show you how to simply convert a synchronization method to asynchronous method.

Comment: I applied the changes to my app by following your example.
When I run the program it crashes on a line of my method rendered async:
Message = The application called an interface that was maintained in order for a different thread. What should I do? Anyway, a very big thank you for your advice.

Comment: @MarcelDelhaye Does this line touch the app's UI? If so, you need to use [CoreDispatcher.RunAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.core.coredispatcher.runasync).

Answer (score 0):

I added this code in the first page:

```
private async void AddFavori_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
        MyProgressRing.IsActive = true;
    });
    await Task.Delay(1000);

    Frame.Navigate(typeof(ChoixFavoris), currentListeAchat);

    await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
        MyProgressRing.IsActive = false;
    });
}
```

Also, I have the ProgressRing on the first page during the data loading.